# $f(x)=xg(x)$. Does the continuity of $f$ implies that $g$ is also continuous everywhere except zero?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, continuity, vectors

Let $f:\mathbb R^{m\times n}\to\mathbb R^m$ be a continuous function.

$x\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$.

$g:\mathbb R^{m\times n}\to \mathbb R^n$.

$g(x)$ is a column vector, and $f(x)=xg(x)$.

Is it possible to conclude that $g$ is continuous everywhere except at zero?

It can also be easily shown that $g$ is continuous always imply the continuity of $f$.

Thank you for letting me know that $g(x)$ is not necessarily continuous at zero by counterexamples.

---

We assume that $x>0$ i.e. positive-semi-definite

Comment: In the one-dimensional case, take $g(x)=\sin(1/x)$  Then $f$ is continuous, $g$ is not.

Comment: At least in the one-dimensional case, you can however deduce that $g$ is continuous everywhere except possibly at $0$.

Comment: @Thorgott Is it possible to prove that?

Comment: @HighGPA Yes, because in the one-dimensional case, you have $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$ for $x\neq0$ and the quotient of two continuous functions is continuous (granted the denominator is non-zero).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x):\equiv0$, and $g(x):=0$ $(x\ne0)$, $\>g(0):=1$.

Answer (score 1):

No. There will always be a non-continuous $g$ with that property

Suppose that $f(x)=xg(x)$. If $g(x)$ is not continuous we're done. If $g(x)$ is continuous define $g'(x)=g(x)$ whenever $x\not = 0$ and $g'(0)=a$ for any $a$ such that $g(0)\not = a$. Then $g'$ is not continuous but $f(x)=xg'(x)$.

In other words you can always change the value of $g(x)$ at zero so you can't hope that $g$ will always be continuous.

Comment: What if we let $x>0$?

Comment: @HighGPA $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ so I don't know what you mean by $x>0$. Anyway I guess you can study each coordinate separetely, for coordinates of $x$ which are zero you can have many $g$'s with zero at this coordinate, and with coordinates that are not zero you can divide this coordinate by $x$ and you will get a continuous map.